# Pandas to_csv() slow saving large dataframe

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I'm guessing this is an easy fix, but I'm running into an issue that it's taking nearly an hour to save a pandas dataframe to a csv file using the **to_csv()** function. I'm using anaconda python 2.7.12 with pandas (0.19.1).

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

src_files = glob.glob(os.path.join('/my/path', "*.csv.gz"))

# 1 - Takes 2 min to read 20m records from 30 files
for file_ in sorted(src_files):
    stage = pd.DataFrame()
    iter_csv = pd.read_csv(file_
                     , sep=','
                     , index_col=False
                     , header=0
                     , low_memory=False
                     , iterator=True
                     , chunksize=100000
                     , compression='gzip'
                     , memory_map=True
                     , encoding='utf-8')

    df = pd.concat([chunk for chunk in iter_csv])
    stage = stage.append(df, ignore_index=True)

# 2 - Takes 55 min to write 20m records from one dataframe
stage.to_csv('output.csv'
             , sep='|'
             , header=True
             , index=False
             , chunksize=100000
             , encoding='utf-8')

del stage
```

I've confirmed the hardware and memory are working, but these are fairly wide tables (~ 100 columns) of mostly numeric (decimal) data.

Thank you,

Comment: Hardware bottleneck. Keep a tab on your disk throughput, and also check for empty disk space.

Comment: As I mentioned, I did check the disk space and can copy large files to the drive with expected speed. Also, I should have mentioned I'm writing to an SSD (Samsung 950)

Comment: Try without the `chunksize` kwag... It could be a lot of things, like quoting, value conversion, etc. Try to [profile](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/profile.html) it and see where it spends most of its time.

Comment: any update on that? I ran on a similar problem lately

Comment: i have an ssd on pci express and face the same issue. hardware should not be the bottleneck in this case...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54617862/6646912 for a benchmark showing how to speed up writing large DataFrames with mostly numeric data to a csv.

Comment: As an aside, it is totally pointless and unecessarily inefficient to use `chunksize=100000` and then simply `df = pd.concat([chunk for chunk in iter_csv])`. Just don't use the chunksize parameter then! You end up using *more* memory this way and it will definitely be slower

Answer (score 17):

Adding my small insight since the 'gzip' alternative did not work for me - try using to_hdf method.  This reduced the write time significantly!
(less than a second for a 100MB file - CSV option preformed this in between 30-55 seconds)

```
stage.to_hdf(r'path/file.h5', key='stage', mode='w')
```

It is possible to save different data to different key names, so when we save the data, whatever key name we choose will need to be used when reading the data back.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf.html

Comment: This solution works for me, while the .gz solution made no difference. .to_hdf method wrote out 1.5GB in 13 seconds. .to_csv took too long to time, even with changes suggested by Frane

Comment: Yes, the .gz solution made no difference made no difference for a file size of 5GB

Comment: I went from 4 minutes with .to_csv, to 8 seconds with .to_hdf !!!!
Thanks @amir-f !!

Answer (score 14):

You are reading compressed files and writing plaintext file.
Could be IO bottleneck.

Writing compressed file could speedup writing up to 10x

```
    stage.to_csv('output.csv.gz'
         , sep='|'
         , header=True
         , index=False
         , chunksize=100000
         , compression='gzip'
         , encoding='utf-8')
```

Additionally you could experiment with different chunk sizes and compression methods (‘bz2’, ‘xz’).

Comment: Frane, solution did not work. The time taken still remained the same

Comment: @ShreeshaN what did you time? Execution of  `to_csv` method or whole script?

Comment: Execution of to_csv

Comment: @ShreeshaN what size and time are you talking about?
Look at hdf format for alternative. If you need text/csv look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54617862/6646912 as mention in his comment o question.

Comment: thanks for the alternatives. I tried hdf format, to_hdf() is super fast. It took 4 seconds to save a 600mb file with 4 lakh records where as to_csv even after using chunks and compression took 220 seconds. Thanks

Comment: This solution doesn't work. Use to_hdf() (see other answer)

Comment: This does not work as the time taken is still the same

Answer (score 10):

You said "*[...] of mostly numeric (decimal) data.*". Do you have any column with time and/or dates?

I saved an 8 GB CSV in seconds when it has only numeric/string values, but it takes 20 minutes to save an 500 MB CSV with two `Dates` columns. So, what I would recommend is to convert each date column to a string before saving it. The following command is enough:

```
df['Column'] = df['Column'].astype(str)
```

I hope that this answer helps you.

P.S.: I understand that saving as a `.hdf` file solved the problem. But, sometimes, we do need a `.csv` file anyway.

Comment: Also to handle the NaT values you may want df['Column'].astype(str).replace('NaT', '')

Comment: This actually helped with my problem where I had a df of 1406x19221. The first row of mine was characters since I forgot to have the file read with them being the headers. When I made them the headers, I could save the file as csv in seconds. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try either Apache's `parquet` file format, or `polars` package, which is an alternative to the usual `pandas`.

I was trying to cache some data locally from my server, it has 59 millions rows on 9 columns; `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv` simply died therefore couldn't be timed.

I put a breakpoint on the way out and saved it down using `parquet` and read it back into `polars` dataframe (the reading wasn't timed but it was roughly 5-10 seconds):

```
[ins] In [6]:import polars as pl
[ins] In []:pf = pl.read_parquet('path_to_my_data.parquet')
```

I wrote this huge dataframe to csv using `polars`:

```
[ins] In [8]: %timeit pf.write_csv('path_to_my_data.csv')                                                                         
24.3 s ± 5.79 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

I casted `polars` dataframe to a `pandas` one and wrote it down using both `hdf` and `parquet`:

```
[ins] In [9]: df = pf.to_pandas() 
[ins] In [11]: %timeit df.to_parquet('path_to_data2.parquet')                                                                                       
11.7 s ± 138 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

[ins] In [12]: %timeit df.to_hdf('path_to_my_data.h5', key="stage", mode="w")  
15.4 s ± 723 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

The `parquet` file was 1.8G whereas the `h5` file was 4.3G. `to_parquet` from `pandas` has performed compression (`snappy`, `gzip`, or `brotil`), however we as end users don't need to decompress it.

Either of them can be a promising, if not exceeding, alternative if you need to deal with huge amount of data and data query back and forth is a must.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use `to_csv()` to output to company network drive which was too slow and took one hour to output 1GB csv file. just tried to output to my laptop C: drive with `to_csv()` statement, it only took 2 mins to output 1GB csv file.