# Optimizing time in a large loop Pandas to_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a 400.000 rows dataframe (actually, is bigger, but for tests purposes I'm using this dimension).

I need to export to txt/csv multiple files based on two conditions: #RIC and Date.

Looping around these conditions becomes a really slow process, so I'm looking for some faster way to do this.

That's my original idea:

```
def SaveTxt(df, output_folder=None):

# Start time
start_time = time.time()
# Data Frame with date
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date-Time']).dt.date
dates = df['Date'].unique()
ticks = df['#RIC'].unique()

for tick in ticks:
    for date in dates:
        # print(date, tick)
        # Filtering by instrument and date
        temp_df = df[(df['#RIC'] == tick) & (df['Date'] == date)]
        if temp_df.empty:
            pass
        else:
            # Saving files
            if output_folder in [None, ""]:
                temp_df.to_csv("%s_%s.txt" % (date, tick))
            else:
                temp_df.to_csv("%s\\%s_%s.txt" % (output_folder, date, tick))


# Elapsed time
elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
elapsed_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(elapsed_time))
# Priting elapsed time
print('Elapsed time: %s' % elapsed_time)
```

For 400.000 rows (equivalent of 5 days data) it takes 3 minutes to run this script. For one year, takes 6 hours and I didn't tried with 10 years, but I suppose that is not a good idea.

**Solution Idea**

I've tried to remove the data used in each loop from *df*, but this condition is not working (maybe this will remove the size of the data frame and will turn the code faster):

```
df = df[(df['#RIC'] != tick) & (df['Date'] != date)]
```

I believe this should remove every tick AND date from the data frame, but it's applying this condition separably.

I'll appreciate if you guys have some solution for this problem.

Thanks

**Edit**

Don't know if this is the best way to share a sample of the data (I can't upload under a proxy)

```
#RIC    Date       Price    Volume
DIJF21  16/10/2019  4.64    15
DIJF21  16/10/2019  4.64    40
DIJF21  16/10/2019  4.64    100
DIJF21  16/10/2019  4.64    5
DIJF21  16/10/2019  4.64    1765
DIJF21  16/10/2019  4.64    10
DIJF21  16/10/2019  4.64    100
DIJF21  16/10/2019  4.64    1000
DIJF21  16/10/2019  4.64    5
DIJF21  16/10/2019  4.64    20
DIJF21  16/10/2019  4.64    80
DIJF21  16/10/2019  4.64    25
DIJF21  16/10/2019  4.64    25
DIJF21  16/10/2019  4.64    150
DIJF20  15/10/2019  4.905   2000
DIJF20  15/10/2019  4.905   2000
DIJF20  15/10/2019  4.903   10
```

Comment: Your example is working fine for me. If you are uncertain, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful to give a sample of your data to test the answer beforehand. Like this I just hope it works without errors ;)

You should be able to use groupby with a custom function that gets applied to each group like this:

```py
def custom_to_csv(temp_df, output_folder):
    date, tick = temp_df.name
    # Saving files
    if output_folder in [None, ""]:
        temp_df.to_csv("%s_%s.txt" % (date, tick))
    else:
        temp_df.to_csv("%s\\%s_%s.txt" % (output_folder, date, tick))

df.groupby(['Date', '#RIC']).apply(custom_to_csv, (output_folder))
```

EDIT: Changed 
`df` to `temp_df` and `(output_folder,)` to `(output_folder)`

Comment: Could you check my edit? Your solution is way faster than mine, but it's generating only one file.

Comment: There were indeed two bugs in my code. Is it working for you now?

Comment: @rpanai I edited the Edit description. Is there something else? I believe you are allowed to edit it as well.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you consider the coroutines
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html

something like that:

```
import asyncio


df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date-Time']).dt.date
dates = df['Date'].unique()
ticks = df['#RIC'].unique()


async def tick_func(tick):
    for date in dates:
        temp_df = df[(df['#RIC'] == tick) & (df['Date'] == date)]
        if temp_df.empty:
            pass
        else:
            if output_folder in [None, ""]:
                temp_df.to_csv("%s_%s.txt" % (date, tick))
            else:
                temp_df.to_csv("%s\\%s_%s.txt" % (output_folder, date, tick))



asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = [tick_func(tick) for tick in ticks]
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
loop.close()
```

Comment: Hey @lestat_kim. Could you please describe how the coroutines can be used for solving this task. Just posting the link to the library may not help the user in solving their problem :)

Comment: @ShagunSodhani I edited the answer for an example =)

Comment: Thanks for adding the example @lestat_kim.

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick pass through the question and it seems that the bottleneck is the doubly nested `for` loop that you are using to group the data by `tick` and `date`.

Maybe you could consider performing the `groupby` operation in a single function call using the [`groupby` function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). The code would look something like this:

```
grouped_df = df.groupby(['#RIC', 'Date'])
```

Print `grouped_df` to make sure it looks like the way you expect it to look. Then you can iterate over this grouped dataframe once and save the different groups to the filesystem (as desired).

Please let me know if this works or if you face any other problems.

Edit: To follow up on @Thales comment, there are some [online](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/99prjw/fastest_way_to_export_a_large_dataframe_to_a_csv/) [resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417574/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-output-large-dataframe-into-a-csv-file) that discuss how to save large dataframes to a csv file. From these resources, I like the suggestion of using numpy.

Following is an example (taken from one of the links shared above):

```
aa.to_csv('pandas_to_csv', index=False)
# 6.47 s

df2csv(aa,'code_from_question', myformats=['%d','%.1f','%.1f','%.1f'])
# 4.59 s

from numpy import savetxt

savetxt(
    'numpy_savetxt', aa.values, fmt='%d,%.1f,%.1f,%.1f',
    header=','.join(aa.columns), comments=''
)
# 3.5 s
```

Comment: This seems a good idea to skip a nested loop. Any suggestion about a faster way to save the csv files?

Comment: @ThalesMarques I have updated the answer. I hope it is useful.