# Fastest way to write a dataframe with millions of lines into csv

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

I have a dataframe with ~7 million lines and 18 columns.

What is the fastest library that consumes less time?

Right now I am writing the dataframe using:

```
df.to_csv('file.csv', header=True, index=False)
```

And it is taking me ~3 hours.

The file has ~800 MB.

Is there a faster method/library to speed up the writing process?

Comment: You could try with `numpy.savetxt`: Take a look of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54617862/13676202).

Answer (score 0):

Try using https://pypi.org/project/pyarrow/

I've found it to be 86% faster for reading and 30% faster for writing CSV files as compared to pandas!